# How to reduce the number of database hits while querying in Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have three tables

1. User
2. Device
3. Log

I want to filter the logs based on devices and logs. I'm using the following querying which iterates over the users and devices in order to get the logs. I feel this will become a performance hit. How to reduce the number of database hits?

```
for user_obj in User.objects.all():
    device_qs = Device.objects.filter(user=user_obj)
    if device_qs.exists():
        for device_obj in device_qs:
            log_count = Log.objects.filter(user=user_obj, device=device_obj, created_at__range(from_date, to_date)).count()
```

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: @Jane Using MySQL database backend

Comment: Do you have code for the models? Partial models that show the relationships between the models are sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the log count per user and device (which is what you get from the code you posted), you can get that in just one query:

```
from django.db.models import Count

logs = (Log.objects
    .filter(created_at__range = (from_date, to_date))
    .values('user', 'device')
    .annotate(log_count=Count('device'))
)
```

You can modify the query to include any attributes of the user and device models that you need:

```
.values('user__last_name', 'device__name')  # etc.
```

You can also order the dataset by appending `order_by()` at the end to be able to iterate over it in the desired order:

```
.order_by('user__last_name', '-log_count')
```

Comment: This query skips the devices which does not have logs. But I want the logs to be updated with 0 when there are no logs. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Then you won't  get around querying the `User` (or `Device`) model. You'd have to update the question with the code for the three models so we can think about a query. Do you only want devices with no logs or also users with no logs?

Comment: I want all logs of devices(count) associated with the user irrespective of log count(Both with logs or no logs), having user in `values` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a "proxy model" that references a `view` in your MySQL instance

The view would look like this:

```
SELECT 
t1.*,
t2.*,
t3.*
FROM users t1
RIGHT JOIN device t2 (ON t1.id=t2.user_id)
RIGHT JOIN log t3 (ON t3.device_id=t2.id);
```

Now to create a proxy model, do this:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # all fields from the 3 tables here

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'yourViewNameHere'
        managed = False # this keeps django from creating the table
```

then `python manage.py makemigrations` + `python manage.py migrate` as usual

Now, to access the the data you need, you would do something like this:

```
from django.db import connection
sql = "SELECT * FROM your_view WHERE some_date_column > 'foo' AND some_date_column < 'bar' "

with connection.cursor() as cur:

    cur.execute(sql)
    data = cur.fetchall()

print(data)
```

**Note** that if you are passing parameters to the raw sql query, you should **always** pass them like this to avoid sql injection:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM your_view WHERE some_date_column > %s AND some_date_column < %s"

params = ('foo', 'bar')
with connection.cursor() as cur:

    cur.execute(sql, params)
    data = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer especially for using proxy models in this criteria. But my question, is there a way that we can use the Django ORM way of querying which will avoid writing direct MySQl query